# dynamically get columns from 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a 2D array of row,through which i want get the column coordinates/information just like i got for the row(rowArr2D)

So,in my Column(colArr2D) i'm just getting all 4th position values in the array since i passed have `oRowCount` in the function

my goal is to get all columns respectively.
Example:

```
Row:[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ]

Columns: [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]
```

```js
mockTable = { // mocking the portions of my code
  GetRowsCount : () => 4,
  GetRow: (x) => ({
    GetCellsCount : () => 7,
    GetCell : (x) => x
  })
}

CTable_prototype_GetTableMapping = function(currentTable)
{
        //get row information
    let oRowCount = currentTable.GetRowsCount();
    const rowArr2D = Array(oRowCount);
    for (let i = 0; i < oRowCount; i++) {
        //get cell information and cell count
        let oRow = currentTable.GetRow(i);
        let oCellCount = oRow.GetCellsCount();
        rowArr2D[i] = Array(oCellCount);
        for (let j = 0; j < oCellCount; j++) {
            //get cell content 
            let oCell = oRow.GetCell(j);
            rowArr2D[i][j] = oCell;
        }
    }
    // get column information
    const colArr2D = (array, colCount) => {
        const result = [];

        array.forEach(e => {
            result.push(e[colCount]);
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    };
    colArr2D(rowArr2D, oRowCount);
  return rowArr2D
    console.log(rowArr2D);
};

const theArray = CTable_prototype_GetTableMapping(mockTable);

console.log("full 2D array", theArray)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want.

Comment: @CBroe is the question not so clear? if so will try to make it much more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```js
const colArr2D = (array) => 
  array[0].map((a, i) => 
    array.map(b => b[i])
  );

const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

console.log(colArr2D(arr))
```

Comment: Nice, this actually worked, i did try using `.map` at first but it was giving me `undefined` so i went for `forEach` method.

Comment: How is it possible to work with columns in JavaScript without nested loops?? ```.map``` may be one answer, as well as ```forEach```, however, they very often give me the column stacked in the first row of the array, thus I have to call ```array[0]``` instead of ```array```??

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov map and foreach are just a different kinds of loop, so you're not avoiding any nested loops by using them.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2azk9ryx/) is a version of the above code that doesn't use map or foreach.  I don't know what you mean by the column is stacked up, it sounds like an output problem.

Comment: Maybe it's an output issue: ```Array: [ [1,2,3,4,...] , undefined , ...  ]```. However, it is annoying and happens almost every time, so I have to write ```array[0]``` in order to access the output single row or column from the 2d array.

Comment: By the way JS is so annoying because of such things, like for example if I want to access the first DOM element of the same class, I have to write again ```getElementsByClassName('class')[0].innerHTML```. So I often use 'id' instead of 'class' for multiple elements of the same type.

Comment: An here, I would like to give a big plus to Python over JS for handling datasets.